# How to animate scrolling to the bottom of a div using only JavaScript and not Jquery

Tags: javascript

When the user clicks a button, a div container is automatically scrolled to the bottom. Here is the following code I am using to do this:

```
container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight
```

How do I animate this interaction, so instead of jumping straight to the content, a smooth scroll is implemented?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `scrollIntoView` function:

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => scroll());

function scroll(){
    document.getElementById("reallyTall").scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end"});
}
```

```css
#reallyTall{
  height: 1000px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, lightblue, lightgreen);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="button">
    Click Me
  </button>
  <div id="reallyTall">


  </div>
</div>
```